# Data transferring format

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite

I need to download onto my devices some data in multiple files.
Then this data will be copied to application's local db (this is SQLite db, however in future this may be Compact SQL on WInPhone).

What is the best format for such files?

I am considering such possibilities:

1. SQLited db file - possibly this will be easy to copy to my db. My current prefferance.
2. JSON format. Maybe not enough compact because column name will be repeating.
3. CSV - it allows to store only one table but I would prefer have few tables in one file
4. XML - I do not see any prefferaces over json.

Comment: compressed encrypted binary blob.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the most popular, human-readable, easy to use format. There's tons of supporting libraries, native and not, for all OSs. It's fast and reliable. You can easily update the data you pass with it without updating the apps (which you cannot by passing an SQLite database and would be difficult with a CSV file). XML is being slowly deprecated for data communications... but if you see some special advantage with XML (parsing the XML directly, which is not as effective with JSON yet, for example), go for it. I'd choose JSON anyway, it's the current standard and will still be for a long time.